# copy paste if not cell value is blank vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy non blank cells text and paste to other sheet. It is not able paste and the column is blank.No errors poping up

My code:

```
Sub mycode()
Dim rngFiltered As Range 
On Error Resume Next
Set rngFiltered = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("K2:K25").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rngFiltered Is Nothing Then
    rngFiltered.Copy Sheets("sheet2").Range("K2")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: are the values in those cells filled with a formula that returns `""` or a constant?

Comment: The return value is either text or " " from the formula

Comment: Then xlCellTypeConstants will not work.  You can loop through the range, copy the values to another range then use the xlCellTypeConstants, or load it into an array and cycle through the array.

Comment: Would .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlCellTypeConstants) work?